# Audio jack not working properly in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, audio, headphones

The audio jack on the front panel of my [HP TouchSmart IQ770](http://reviews.cnet.com/desktops/hp-touchsmart-iq770/4507-3118_7-32305738.html?tag=psum) is not working correctly in Ubuntu (9.10 and 8.04). When I connect a headphone or a speaker to the jack, Ubuntu plays sound in both speakers - the default integrated speakers and the newly connected device. Vista mutes the integrated speaker and switches to the connected device, which is the behavior I'm looking for. This is not a `9.10` specific issue because I had the same issue with `8.04` too (and I couldn't solve it then).

I tried manually changing the 'Connector' option to 'Analog Headphones' (from the default 'Analog Output') in `Sound Preferences|Output` tab - but both the inbuilt speaker and headphones went silent.

I tried the workaround found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=314383) but it didn't work for me. I added `options snd-hda-intel model=hp` (tried `model=auto` too) to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` but that didn't work either.

Here are some info that (I believe) might be required to understand the issue.

```
$cat /proc/asound/version 
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.20.
```

---

```
$lspci 
//among other things
00:10.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP51 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
```

---

```
$cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                     HDA NVidia at 0xfbfb8000 irq 23
1 [SAA7134        ]: SAA7134 - SAA7134
                     saa7133[0] at 0xfebff800 irq 17
```

---

```
$/proc/asound/modules 
0 snd_hda_intel
1 saa7134_alsa
```

Can someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of Googling and dozens or reboots, I got it working with the help of [this post in ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=806620).

The solution is simple: add the following line to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and reboot the machine.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=6stack
```

That line originally contained `power_save`, `power_save_controller`, `position_fix` and `probe_mask` variables along with the `model` variable that was set to `auto`. Sound did not work when I retained existing values for other variables and set `model=6stack`. I had to strip them off to get it working.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Actually this disables the system's inbuilt speaker no matter what - but at least I can use head phones without disturbing my colleagues. I am accepting this until someone comes up with a better solution.